# How to create a PSR-4 autoloader for my project?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, autoloader, psr-4

I am creating a PHP project and want to implement PSR-4 autoloading.

I don't know which files I need to create in the vendor directory to implement autoloading for class files.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you are using `composer`, you do not create the autoloader but let `composer` do its job and create it for you.

The only thing you need to do is create the appropriate configuration on `composer.json` and execute `composer dump-autoload`.

E.g.:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"App\\": "src/"}
    }
}
```

By doing the above, if you have a file structure like this

```
├── src/
│   ├── Controller/
│   ├── Model/
│   ├── View/
│   └── Kernel.php
├── public/
│   └── index.php
└── vendor/
```

After executing `composer dump-autoload` the autoloader will be generated on `vendor/autoload.php`.

All your classes should be nested inside the `App` namespace, and you should put only one class per file.

E.g.:

```
<?php /* src/Controller/Home.php */

namespace App\Controller;

class Home { /* implementation */ }
```

And you need only to include the autoloader in your entry-point script (e.g. `index.php`).

```
<?php

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Which will allow you to simply load your classes directly from anywhere after this point, like this:

```
use App\Controller\Home;

$homeController = new Home();
```

This is explained at the docs, [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).