# Php 7.4.3 Class not found

Tags: php

This is my project path configuration

`./create.php`

`/Install/Install.php`

## create.php

```
<?php

use Install\Install;

echo "Starting";
$install = new Install();
```

This gives me the error

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Install\Install' not found in /project/create.php:6**

## Install.php

```
<?php

namespace Install;

class Install
{
    //whatever
}
```

Can someone explain me what is happening there ?

Obviously I guess that using a `require_once` line with my filename would probably fix the issue...but I thought using namespace and use import could prevent me from doing that like we do in classic framework like symfony / magento ?

I've seen some post speaking about autoloading, but i'm a little bit lost. Haven't been able to find a clear explanation on the other stack topic neither.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918843/how-to-create-a-psr-4-autoloader-for-my-project

Comment: Thanks for assist, but I'm not sure to understand; does it means I have to use composer for that ? If I have to then which module should I require on my compose ? And is there anyway to do that without a specific module, cause I'm not sure I will have ssh access later on my project out of local development which might be a problem if I need to run composer.

Comment: It's up to you if you want to use compose, you can also go with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571391/psr4-auto-load-without-composer

Comment: @NigelRen Indeed I've seen that `spl_autoload_register` in the post you mentionned, and in the following answer, I will dig into all that and trying to understand these doncepts. Thanks for your sharing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP compiles code one file at a time. It doesn't have any native concept of a "project" or a "full program".

There are three concepts involved here, which complement rather than replacing each other:

- **Namespaces** are just a way of naming things. They allow you to have two classes called `Install` and still tell the difference between them. The `use` statement just tells the compiler (within one file) which of those classes you want when you write `Install`. The PHP manual has [a chapter on namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) which goes into more detail on all of this.
- **Require and include** are the *only* mechanisms that allow code in one file to reference code in another. At some point, you need to tell the compiler to load "Install.php".
- **Autoloading** is a way for PHP to *ask your code* which file it should load, when you mention a class it hasn't seen the definition for yet. The first time a class name is encountered, any function registered with `spl_autoload_register` will be called with that class name, and then has a chance to run include/require to load the definition. There is a fairly brief [overview of autoloading in the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

So, in your example:

- `use Install\Install;` just means "when I write `Install`, I really mean `Install\Install`"
- `new Install()` is translated by the compiler to `new Install\Install()`
- the class `Install\Install` hasn't been defined; if an autoload function has been registered, it will be called, with the string "Install\Install" as input
- that autoload function can then look at that class name, and run `require_once __DIR__ . '/some/path/Install.php';`

You can write the autoload function yourself, or you can use an "off-the-shelf" implementation where you just have to configure the directory where your classes are, and then follow a convention for how to name them.

Comment: Simple, clear and understandable answer. Thanks you very much. I will dig into this `spl_autoload_register`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to Use class from another file, you must `include` or `require` the file.

Use `require('Install.php');` before `use Install\Install;`.

If you are planning to do a big project I would recommend to use PHP frameworks rather than coding from scratch.