# One File vs Multiple Files (OOP)

Tags: php, oop

First of all, english is not my first language so apologies for the gramatics errors,

i has build a program php and i have 1 file for every class i create like Core.php.

```
<?php
class Core{

}
?>
```

i use a for loop to require all files before even start de program but it seesms very expensive task for the interpreter.

i was thinking on build 1 php file that contain all classes that needed.

so what option i use?

i expect the better performance since i am talking about 20 classes or more

Comment: May be worth reading about autoloading (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651509/what-is-autoloading-how-do-you-use-spl-autoload-autoload-and-spl-autoload-re) and perhaps PSR-4 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918843/how-to-create-a-psr-4-autoloader-for-my-project)

Comment: If you use one file per class, it would make using an autoloader much easier, then you wouldn't have to require all the files as the autoloader would just pull in the ones that are needed

Answer (score -1):

The "one class per one file" is the correct option.

As @NigelRen mentioned in the comment, you should not manually handle the *including* of the classes, but instead - use autoloader. The ideal option would be to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) for this.

As for your performance worries - it's not how this works. PHP does not read the files from the disk all the time. Instead the class files get cached (stored in RAM, in a pre-compiled form).

P.S.

You example made a bit worried - having "core" or "context", or "system" classes is something of *code smell*, that indicates you might be doing something wrong. In this particular case - creating a "god class". That would be a bad idea.

P.P.S.

You do not need to use the closing `?>` tag, if there is nothing after it. Actually having it is actively harmful - it's one of the most popular caused of "Header already sent" warning.